# PostgreSQL return JSON objects as key-value pairs

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

A PostgreSQL instance stores data in JSONB format:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (
    id   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data JSONB     NOT NULL
)
```

The data array might contain objects like:

```
{
  "observations": {
    "temperature": {
      "type": "float",
      "unit": "C",
      "value": "23.1"
    },
    "pressure": {
      "type": "float",
      "unit": "mbar",
      "value": "1011.3"
    }
  }
}
```

A selected row should be returned as key-value pairs in a format like:

```
temperature,type,float,value,23.1,unit,C,pressure,type,float,value,1011.3,unit,mbar
```

The following query returns at least each object, while still JSON:

```
SELECT id, value FROM mytable JOIN jsonb_each_text(mytable.data->'observations') ON true;
1 | {"type": "float", "unit": "mbar", "value": 1140.5}
1 | {"type": "float", "unit": "C", "value": -0.9}
5 | {"type": "float", "unit": "mbar", "value": "1011.3"}
5 | {"type": "float", "unit": "C", "value": "23.1"}
```

But the results are splitted and not in text format.

How can I return key-value pairs of all objects in `data`?

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired output with columns as well, as I can't tell if that's one big string or a bunch of column names.

Comment: Actually, I just need to output the fetched rows in CSV format. The keys are not required, so `temperature,float,23.1,C,pressure,float,1011.3,mbar` would be sufficient, too.

Comment: Do you know that it will always contain "temperature" and "pressure", or could you have keys in there with any names?

Comment: It could be any name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will flatten the json structure and effectively just concatenate the values, along with the top-level key names (e.g. temperature and pressure), for the expected "depth" level. See if this is what you had in mind.

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(conc, ',')
      FROM (
        SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', key, STRING_AGG(value, ',')) AS conc
        FROM (
          SELECT key, (jsonb_each_text(value)).value
          FROM jsonb_each(data->'observations')
        ) AS x
        GROUP BY key
      ) AS csv
    ) AS csv
FROM mytable
```

Result:

```
| id  | csv                                                 |
| --- | --------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | pressure,float,mbar,1011.3,temperature,float,C,23.1 |
| 2   | pressure,bigint,unk,455,temperature,int,F,45        |
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ada5mtMgYn5acshi3WLR7S/0

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. I’ll figure out the details of your query by my own.

Comment: Is it also possible to return all elements as an SQL array, instead of a concatenated string? Wouldn’t it be even easier?

Comment: @laserbrain Sort of, but if you put all of those comma delimited values in a single array then you lose ordering. Depends on what you do with it I guess; if you keep them in the array then any initial ordering when creating the array will be maintained, but as soon as you unnest it it's no longer guaranteed unless you reorder it, and any ordering will push e.g. "pressure" into some unknown index which may have no relation to its values.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is it further possible to include `id` in the returned element `csv` using `STRING_AGG`, e.g. `2,pressure,bigint,unk,455,temperature,int,F,45`?

Comment: I didn’t know I can simply add further elements to `CONCAT_WS()`. Thank you for your efforts.